# Rspec model testing - current_user in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, public-activity

I am using the public_activity gem to generate activity feeds in my app, and in my model, I am using devise's current_user to identify the owner of the activity.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: ->(controller, model) { controller.current_user }
  ...
end
```

I realize that referencing current_user in the model is not the norm, but this is how they [recommend doing it](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/wiki/%5BHow-to%5D-Set-the-Activity%27s-owner-to-current_user-by-default).

This works fine in the app, but I am running into trouble with my Rspec tests, where I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(create(:question)).to be_valid
NoMethodError:
undefined method `current_user' for nil:NilClass
# ./app/models/question.rb:8:in `block in <class:Question>'
# ./spec/models/question_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The test itself is typical:

```
describe "Factory" do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(create(:question)).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Here is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    title { Faker::Lorem.characters(30) }
    body { Faker::Lorem.characters(150) }
    user_id { 1 }
    tag_list { "test, respec" }
  end
end
```

How do I get this current_user method in my model to work in my tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I don't think you should reference the `controller` from within the `model`. Because you don't want to instantiate a `controller` object every time you want to access the `model`.

For example you might want to access the `model` from a background worker: who's your `current_user` and what's your `controller`?

The same applies to your test suite. You want to test your `model`, not your `controller`.

Also you might not always want to track activity.

A better approach is to pass in the `current_user` object from the `controller`. Ryan Bates has a nice example in his [Railscast on Public Activity](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?view=asciicast) (see "Excluding Actions"):

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Common
end
```

And for every activity you want to track

```
@question.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid putting the create_activity in every method, but you are right - this is the way to go. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the RSpec helpers in `spec/support/devise.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

You find more info [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have that in spec/support/devise.rb, and current_user is working fine in the controllers. It is just the model tests where I get this error.

Comment: My bad. Although it looks like that the problem is `controller` being nil, not the absence of `current_user`